# MongoDB push array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor

I have a mongodb query which gives me back 2 fields (110, 1; 105, 1; 105, 2). Now, I want to write this results into an array, so that I can use them in a while function:

```
110, 1
105, 1
105, 2
```

I write following function, but in the moment the array is not filed.

```
  'otherHelperFunction': function(){
  var array = {};
  var finalSpielertemp = UserSpieler.find({UserID: 1}).map(function(doc) {
    {$push: array{doc.SpielerID, doc.SpieltagID}};
  });
}
```

How must I define an array? I think var array = {} will not be correct and how is the right push into the array?

I hope anyone can give me a tip. Thanks.

Comment: i think you need to learn javascript first

Comment: The whole code makes no sense. Maybe you are calling "array" an object? I think you may need to learn the basics before you try meteor.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your code and your explanation makes no sense. I have no idea what you are trying to do so I can't help you with it.

You seem to be confused between what an object is and what an array is. Here is a *very* simple explanation of the difference. I urge you to learn the basics of JavaScript using an online course [like this one](https://www.udacity.com/course/javascript-basics--ud804)!

An array is defined like this:

`var array = [];`

An object is defined like this:

`var object = {};`

Arrays store data like this:

`[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]`

Objects store data like this:

`{ name: "Ben", age: 25, country: "France" }`